# Інститут науково-дослідний чи науково-дослідницький?

Tags: вибір-слова, пароніми

Згідно з «Словником української мови» в 11 томах, *дослідний* і *дослідницький* є синонімами в значенні "пов'язаний з науковим дослідженням":

> [ДОСЛІ́ДНИЦЬКИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/doslidnycjkyj), а, е.
>
> 1. Прикм. до дослідник. Завдання цієї дослідницької групи було відшукати морський шлях з Обської губи в Єнісей (Видатні вітчизняні географи.., 1954, 30);
>      // **Пов'язаний з науковим дослідженням**. — Здається мені, що спершу нам, так би мовити, дослідникам, треба буде завоювати собі право на таку розкіш, як дослідницька праця... (Юрій Шовкопляс, Інженери, 1956, 125).
> 2. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [ДО́СЛІДНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/doslidnyj), а, е.
>
> 1. **Пов'язаний з науковим дослідженням**. Йому пропонували залишитися на науковій роботі в дослідному будівельному інституті (Олександр Копиленко, Вибр., 1953, 27).
> 2. <…>

Чи можна вважати взаємозамінними прикметники *дослідний* і *дослідницький* на означення наукової установи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53396/30698.html):

> **Дослідний**. Який стосується досліду, пов’язаний з науковим
>   дослідженням; **призначений для проведення дослідів**. Вж. зі сл.: робота,
>   гурток, завод, **інститут**, центр, ділянка, лабораторія, організація,
>   станція, установа, господарство, підприємство, поле, рослини, тварини.
>
> **Дослідницький**. 1. Який стосується дослідника, належний йому. Вж. зі
>   сл.: колектив, група, задум, інтерес, метод, підхід, рівень, характер,
>   діяльність, енергія, настанова, праця. 2. **Призначений для проведення
>   дослідів**: дослідницька кімната (*коментар від мене (P.Vovk): інституту тут не бачимо)*.

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82):

> Науко́во-до́слідний і́нститут (НДІ) — самостійна установа, створена
>   організовувати наукові дослідження та провадити
>   дослідно-конструкторські роботи, різновид інституту.

Ґуґл:

[Дослідний інститут](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%22&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&lr=lang_uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5x6Dq2_PZAhXPPFAKHVlxCx4QpwUIHw&biw=1366&bih=662) - 227 000 результатів.

[Дослідницький інститут](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=lang_uk&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1uk&ei=JjutWq3LPKmC6ASf4pOQDA&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%22&oq=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i5i30k1l2j0i30k1l2j0i5i30k1l4.3328.5390.0.5607.13.13.0.0.0.0.135.1302.0j11.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.10.1171...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.tyb5mB-0GHg) - 24 000 результатів.

Отже, зважаючи на словники, звісно, це є взаємозамінні слова, частина їхніх значень збігається, але набагато частіше (на порядок) в парі з іменником "інститут" вживається само прикметник "дослідний".